# get notification when user comes near to a marker - osmdroid

Tags: android, gps, location, osmdroid

I'm currently trying to build an app where the user gets a notification when he is near to a marker or in my case I'm using the ItemizedOverlay of Osmdroid and I was wondering if there is a way to do that also for several hundreds of markers without emptying the battery in a few minutes.
I saw a few methods but there all were just for the case, when you have just a few markers.
I would be very happy if someone could help me.

Comment: How often do you need to check where the "markers"  are or is this a static list? What criteria do you have for ".. is near to a marker.."?

Comment: @Barns The locations of the markers don't change only my own location changes and near to a marker should mean like 10-20 meters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Markers have static locations you won't need to load them repeatedly.

If all you want is to calculate the distance between two points on the earth and you have the coordinates in latitude and longitude then there is no need for any Google API's Maps or other libraries. That just costs extra overhead and maintenance. Just make a static method like this:

```
public static double getDistanceMeters(LatLng pt1, LatLng pt2){
    double distance = 0d;
    try{
        double theta = pt1.longitude - pt2.longitude;
        double dist = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pt1.latitude)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pt2.latitude))
                + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pt1.latitude)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pt2.latitude)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta));

        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = Math.toDegrees(dist);
        distance = dist * 60 * 1853.1596;
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return distance;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
public static boolean checkDistanceIsClose(LatLng pt1, LatLng pt2, double distance){
    boolean isInDistance = false;
    try{
        double calcDistance = getDistanceMeters(pt1, pt2)

        if(distance <= calcDistance){
            isInDistance = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return isInDistance;
}
```

Same algorithm will work for any platform. Just translate it to the appropriate program language.

Comment: The problem is, that I would have to calculate the distance to all markers every few seconds and that wouldn't be that power efficient.

Comment: @huhn3k :: You seem to be a bit confused. The power required to perform the above computations for a few hundred GPS coordinates every few seconds is actually quite small.  On the other hand, using the GPS sensor (which is what you need to get the 10-20 m accuracy) for obtaining the GPS coordinates every few seconds is the true power sucker--which is why Google tries to deter developers from relying to heavily on the GPS sensor. Obtaining precise location data at the the short time interval is your problem--NOT the simple geometry calculations described above.

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit confused. You're right. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

To complement @Barns answer, 2 remarks:

- when using osmdroid, you don't have LatLng, you have GeoPoint instead,
- and you don't need to write your own getDistanceMeters because GeoPoint already has
  this method:

  GeoPoint.distanceToAsDouble(final IGeoPoint other)